# Is there a way to automate fishing in forsaken world?

Tags: forsaken-world

I've just taken the fishing job and have been trying to level the skill. Unfortunately it's quite dull and seems to require clicking every 6 seconds. Is there a (legal) way I can automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually found an "auto fish" skill in my skills list.